# I use a box-shadow css but it doesn't work in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, rgba

I use a box-shadow css but it doesn't work in IE8. There is a code as filter: progid... but how can I convert my shadow style from rgba? Here is my code;

```
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(217,217,217,1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(217,217,217,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(217,217,217,1);
```

Comment: that colour is equivalent to `#d9d9d9` see http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on Internet Explorer as well..

```
.box-shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
  zoom: 1;
  filter:
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=0,strength=1),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=45,strength=1),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=90,strength=2),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=3),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=10),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=225,strength=3),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=270,strength=2),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=315,strength=1);

}
body:last-child .box-shadow {
  /* Remove filter from IE9 */
  filter: none;
}

.demo {
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: #555;
  font: 83%/130% arial;
  margin: 20px;      
  padding: 20px;
}    


 <div class="demo box-shadow">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mi
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
  </div>
```

Try out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0bcz1zsm/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This url will help you for lower version of ie

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Have a try of css3pie.com htc file to make IE8 support some new CSS3 properties like box-shadow, rounded corners etc...